# Can CCAnimations be paused?

Tags: animation, cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d

I am new to cocos2d. I am using CCAnimation. It's working fine, except I want to pause the animation occasionally. How do I do this?

Here's what I'm doing so far:

```
[mySprite runAction:[CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:[CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:walkAnim]]];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pause all the actions for a node, but not individually.

Basically you can do something like this

```
[[CCActionManager sharedManager] pauseTarget:node];

[[CCActionManager sharedManager] resumeTarget:node];
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no pause per se. You can use stopAction or stopActionByTag to stop it and run it again when you want to resume.

Check the API [here](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/api-ref/1.0.0/interface_c_c_node.html#a6d2592ff2d9c559f25b4b1a6c01a5dc8) for these methods.